# static block in Dropdown menu

Tags: static-block, drop-downs

I found a way to add a static block in a dropdown. I edited the renderer.phtml in **page/html/topmenu** and added:

```
$html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
$html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
$staticBlock = trim($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')-
>setBlockId($child->getId())->toHtml());
if(!empty($staticBlock)){
$html .= '<span>';
$html .= $staticBlock;
$html .= '</span>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
```

Now I want t show a different static block in every menu items dropdown. So based on the top category, a different static block should be called.

What would be the best way to do that?

The code I used is this:

```
staticBlock = trim($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('top-5')->toHtml());
    $html .= '<span class="nav-static-block">';
    $html .= $staticBlock;
    $html .= '</span>';
    $html .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: Can you add more details about the top category you are talking about? From your code it seems like you can create different static blocks with different ids and it will be displayed in menu section.

Comment: Here I can see you have different static block contents for each menu item. Now can you explain what is the issue here?

Comment: I updated the code above. It only calls one static block for all menu items. I need to show different blocks for different menu-items. So the satic block must be a variable based on category-ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use your first code,

```
$html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
$html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
$staticBlock = trim($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')-
>setBlockId($child->getId())->toHtml());
if(!empty($staticBlock)){
    $html .= '<span>';
    $html .= $staticBlock;
    $html .= '</span>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
```

All you need to do is to update your static block ids like `category-node-8` here `category-node-` will be static and `8` will be the id of the category.

If you have a static block with ID `top-5` change its id to `category-node-5` and it will get displayed under your category with ID `5`.

Comment: That is it. Thanks! That is what I wondered about the first code: how to make it relate to the category